# Is it possible to define subgraphs (clusters) in Graphviz with a specified, fixed layout

Tags: graphviz

How can I create subgraphs/clusters in Graphviz, with nodes at specific positions, and then have Graphviz rotate and arrange these subgraphs according to a set of interconnecting edges (i.e. edges not within the subgraphs)?

Here's my current attempt. Problem is that I want to be able to define the internal ordering of the nodes, such that, as an example, the nodes in subgraph "3" are aligned in a row (and always ordered A-B-C):

```
graph {
    forcelabels=true
    color=lightgrey

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node[shape=point]  
        {rank=same r1A r1B}
        label="1"
        r1A [xlabel="A", fontsize=7]
        r1B [xlabel="B", fontsize=7]
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        node[shape=point]
        {rank=same r2A r2B}
        label="2"
        r2A [xlabel="A", fontsize=7]
        r2B [xlabel="B", fontsize=7]
    }

    subgraph cluster_3 {
        node[shape=point]
        {rank=same volA volB volC}
        label="3"
        volA [xlabel="A", fontsize=7]
        volB [xlabel="B", fontsize=7]
        volC [xlabel="C", fontsize=7]
    }
}
```

[image]

If I add edges, I want Graphviz to be able to rotate the subgraphs, but while preserving that internal layout and ordering. Here, using engine `fdp`, subgraph "3" gets all rearranged (for obvious reasons, since I haven't got any way of fixing the layout):

[image]

And what about more advanced "layouts"? Is it possible/feasible to make a subgraph resembling a microcontroller, something like this:

[image][image]

Comment: I also tried using records, but these don't seem to be rotated. They are always horizontal or vertical, whatever is specified (hard coded) in the node.

Comment: Don't know what "arrange these subgraphs according to a set of interconnecting edges" means, but Graphiz is not well suited to your request.  Consider pikchr (https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md)  or dpic (https://gitlab.com/aplevich/dpic)

Comment: The "interconnecting edges" is simply a set of connections between the nodes of subgraphs :) I tried to make a simple example, where (as is almost the case) subgraph "1" is rotated 90 degrees, and so should "3" -- but while preserving the linear arrangement of its internal nodes

Comment: Also, the main point of all this is to have some algorithm/heuristic to arrange and rotate the subgraphs, such that the edges (i.e the routing) is as simple as possible. Graphviz does this kind of "energy minimization" very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately, none of the Graphviz engines do node rotation.  You would have to create a complete engine for node rotation (the architecture supports this) or a pre/post processor just for node rotation (more later)
- Also Graphviz only seems to support text rotation at a Root graph level.  This might be a killer, depending on your requirements.
- If you want to use clusters (suggestion: nope), you probably need to use the **dot** engine to line up your nodes.
- Html-records (possibly with included images) would probably be a "better" choice for the ICs.  Again, none of the engines will rotate them, but ...
- Cycles are cheap, so if there are not "too many" ICs, generate all possibilities (each IC rotated & not) and then eyeball evaluate or write a post-processing program to determine the "best" result.
- Also note that Graphviz edge routing might not produce what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the great overview :) To clarify, perhaps, I don't want/need Graphviz to produce any usable _routing_, as such, in terms of electrical tracing. My aim is to get some kind of help on positioning and rotating of the components on the board, before EagleCAD etc then does the actual (auto) routing. There doesn't seem to be any tool (that I've found, with only basic looking online) that does "auto populating/placing". So, while the edges in the input to Graphviz do correspond to the connections in the circuit, only the node _positions_ are relevant in the output (what Graphviz produces).

Comment: So I guess I'm looking for another software/algorithm, which handles `layout of graph with clusters`, while preserving the internal layout of clusters. While I'm googling and looking around, perhaps someone has any good tips? :)

Comment: I found Cytoscape (https://cytoscape.org), which is based on (or at least incorporates) a lot of the work done by the developers/researchers behind the Dunnart software. Seems promising! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423020/define-and-preserve-compound-node-shape-in-cytoscape-allowing-rotation