# Define (and preserve) compound node shape in Cytoscape, allowing rotation

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Is it possible to specify a *shape* (i.e. square, or triangle) of a compound node in Cytoscape, which will be preserved when the layout of the graph is computed/rendered? The compound nodes should be rotated freely, as needed to give a good/simple layout.

As an example, consider the graph below with three compound nodes, `I - III`. Compound nodes `II` and `III` could be rotated to give a simple layout. Importantly, the internal layout of compound nodes is *not* affected (`I` remains a triangle, and the other two remain linear).

Is is possible to define such a graph, and get a similar output, using Cytoscape.js?

[image]

Or maybe a slightly more complex example where all three nodes are rotated

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
elements: [
  // nodes
  
  { data: { id: 'IA', parent: 'I' } },
  { data: { id: 'IB', parent: 'I' } },
  { data: { id: 'IC', parent: 'I' } },
  { data: { id: 'I' } },
  
  { data: { id: 'IIA', parent: 'II' } },
  { data: { id: 'IIB', parent: 'II' } },
  { data: { id: 'IIC', parent: 'II' } },
  { data: { id: 'II' } },
  
  { data: { id: 'IIIA', parent: 'III' } },
  { data: { id: 'IIIB', parent: 'III' } },
  { data: { id: 'III' } },
  
  // edges
  {
    data: {
      id: '1',
      source: 'IA',
      target: 'IIA'
    }
  },
    {
    data: {
      id: '2',
      source: 'IC',
      target: 'IIB'
    }
  },
    {
    data: {
      id: '3',
      source: 'IC',
      target: 'IIIA'
    }
  },
    {
    data: {
      id: '4',
      source: 'IB',
      target: 'IIIB'
    }
  },
],
layout: {
    name: 'grid'
},
style: [
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            label: 'data(id)'
        }
    }]    
});

cy.layout({
    name: 'fcose'
}).run();
```

which gives this

[image]

Comment: I see I might be able to use alignment constraints (using `fcose`) but that seems to prevent the compound node from being _rotated_ . If I specify, e.g. `alignmentConstraint: { horizontal: [ [ 'IIIA', 'IIIB' ] ] }` then that's (obviously) what I get. I want to just enforce a _linear_ constraint on nodes `IIIA, IIIB` and `IIA, IIB, IIC`. The triangle in compound `I` would probably be possible by enforcing a linear constraint along one side, as on `IA, IB` (omitting `IC`).
https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Cytoscape desktop doesn't support rotation of compound nodes either, unfortunately.

Comment: I've been checking out all the graph tools/libraries I could find (including Graphviz, which I have some experience using) and I can't seem to find any support for layout while preserving shapes and labelling (under rotation). Is this interesting in itself (that noone supports it)? It seems like a useful thing to have. Grouping and locking subsets of nodes, does that increase the complexity of the overall graph layout problem? Could it maybe be that it somehow might _simplify_ the problem, since it limits the "degrees of freedom"?

Comment: Ideally, I'd have a layout tool which combines shapes like this with the ability to constrain nodes (or bigger shapes) wrt. each other, such as the (horizontal and vertical) constraints supported by Cytoscape/fcose etc.